# How can i avoid app forcefully closing error

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification

App is designed in the way that it will check for Firebase ID on launching. If not,he will be taken to a Registration Activity. If already registered, he will be taken to home activity instead.

Along with this I have configured for click_action of push notification in launcher activity.

On the first opening, user can complete registration completes and open homeactivity as well. But when App is once closed and opened, App crash with message "forcefully closed".

When i checked in the Logcat, error showing is "null object at string line  `switch (clickaction){` .

please advise how can i rectify this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;
    String clickaction;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentuser1 =firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (getIntent().getExtras() == null){

            if (currentuser1!= null) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(homeIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
            }
            else {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent regintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Registration_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(regintent);
                        finish();

                    }
                },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);


            }

        }
        else
        {
            clickaction = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("openactivity");

            Intent intent=new Intent();
            switch (clickaction){

                case "Act1":
                    intent=new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
                    break;
                case "Act2":
                    intent=new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
                    break;
                case "Act3":
                    intent=new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
            startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Obviously, there is no extra `openactivity` on the intent.

Comment: @Henry its the key I am using in Firebase cloud messaging console for clickaction...how can i import it properly